# How to get current element id using class name in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have the current element id using class name when I hover on the element.

To be clear, when I hover on first element(Number 1) it should popup only the id of first element i.e, 1;

Here is the code I'm using

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.number').hover(function(){
 $('.number').each(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('id'));
 });
 });
 });

 <p class="number" id="1">Number 1</p>
 <p class="number" id="2">Number 2</p>
  p class="number" id="3">Number 3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the loop. `this` inside the hover callbacks is the element the event occurs on

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.number').hover(function(){    
     alert($(this).attr('id')); // or simpler `this.id`
  }, function(){
    // do something when mouse leaves
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.number').hover(function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number" id="1">Number 1</p>
<p class="number" id="2">Number 2</p>
<p class="number" id="3">Number 3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.number').hover(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });

});

 <p class="number" id="1">Number 1</p>
 <p class="number" id="2">Number 2</p>
 <p class="number" id="3">Number 3</p>
```

this will alert id on hover of each `<p>` tag